# How can I use Tippy.js in a Google Chrome content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, tippyjs

I would like to use Tippy.js in a simple Chrome Extension I am building.  Basically, I want to use Tippy alongside my content script, but I do not know how to include it without using the cdn.

I know I should include it in the manifest.json file with the content_scripts, but you are not supposed to use a cdn link here. If I install the package with node, I get all the files found here: https://unpkg.com/browse/tippy.js@4.3.5/ but I'm not sure which one to link in the manifest file.

Here is what I currently have in my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":[
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "./node_modules/tippy.js/umd/index.min.js",
                "./src/content.js"]
        }
    ],
```

I realize this is probably a silly attempt at including the external library, but I'm just not sure how to include libraries like this that don't come packaged in a single file.

Comment: Do you use any template generator to generate your chrome extension project?

Comment: No, I am not using a template generator.

Comment: I prefer you to use this generator: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension, it allows us to generate a template and we can start to develop Chrome Extension really quick, and the bundle will be smaller after uglified and minified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tippy.js you need popper.js as well

Save this two files in your project 
https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.15.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js
https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.3.5/umd/index.all.min.js

Add this two files in the content script, like you have added

Comment: i downloaded and added both of these scripts to my content_scripts section under js and it gives me the error still that tippy is undefined :(

Comment: @JamesRiback Hi. Did you get some solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

Umd is a choice in this case, because Chrome Extension didn't support `import` and `export` keywords, so choose `node_modules/tippy.js/umd/index.min.js` and make sure that `node_modules` is at the same directory as your `manifest.json` file.

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":[
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "node_modules/tippy.js/umd/index.min.js",
                "src/content.js"
            ],
            "css": [
                "node_modules/tippy.js/themes/light.css"
            ]
        }
]
```